# React: refs throwing an error - 'Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to blur the calendar control on click of add new button, but it is throwing an error. If anyone knows the solution please answer, actually ref is causing problem it says: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="../react.js"></script>
    <script src="../react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="../react-with-addons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .cmnt
        {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background: lavender;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel"> 
        var totalCandidates = {'A':'23/10/2017','B':'24/10/2017','C':'23/10/2017'};       
        class MyComponent extends React.Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    showComponent: false,                    
                };               
            }
            _onButtonClick() {
                console.log(totalCandidates);
                this.setState({
                    showComponent: true,
                });
            }
            _onCalenderChange() {
                console.log(this);
                this.refs.calender.blur();
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Candidate's name</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input type="text" name="" id="" />
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Scheduled interview list
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input type="date" name="" id="" ref='calender' onChange={this._onCalenderChange.bind(this)} />
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <select name="" id=""></select>    
                                    </th>    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>                               
                        </table>
                        <button onClick={this._onButtonClick.bind(this)}>Add new</button>
                        {this.state.showComponent ? <MyComponent /> : null  }
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }  
        ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.getElementById("example"));                       
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script ordering
from

```
<script src="../react.js"></script>
<script src="../react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="../react-with-addons.js"></script>
```

ordering to

```
<script src="./lib/react.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to attach a `ref`.
According to the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) you should do it this way:

```
<input ref => {this.myInput = ref} />
```

And you will acess it later like this:

```
this.myInput
```

Here is a running example of your code:

```js
var totalCandidates = {'A':'23/10/2017','B':'24/10/2017','C':'23/10/2017'};       
        class MyComponent extends React.Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    showComponent: false,                    
                };               
            }
            _onButtonClick() {
                console.log(totalCandidates);
                this.setState({
                    showComponent: true,
                });
            }
            _onCalenderChange = () => {
                console.log(this.calendar);
                this.calendar.blur();
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Candidate's name</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input type="text" name="" id="" />
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Scheduled interview list
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input type="date" name="" id="" ref={ref => {this.calendar = ref}} onChange={this._onCalenderChange.bind(this)} />
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <select name="" id=""></select>    
                                    </th>    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>                               
                        </table>
                        <button onClick={this._onButtonClick.bind(this)}>Add new</button>
                        {this.state.showComponent ? <MyComponent /> : null  }
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }  
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.getElementById("example"));
```

```css
.cmnt {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```